# Hard disk drive (SATA) slowed down but SSD still works fine on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I currently have two hard drives, one is SSD (in which my OS is installed) and the other a SATA connected hard drive.

I recently travelled for a week and left my computer turned on.
When I came back I couldn’t open my “Downloads” folder (which is on the SATA hard drive). After further investigation, I found out that I’m unable to open most files on the SATA hard drive, all my Steam games are in there and most won’t open or are really slow.

I already ran malware and viruses checks and couldn’t find anything.
I also tried to update the drivers and had no success.

My SSD seems to work fine, so I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Check the SMART stats and overall health status for the HDD (with Hard Disk Sentinel for example).

Comment: Have you rebooted the machine yet?  Another thing to try is to pull the drive and put it in another machine

Answer (score 0):

*having less than 50 reps, I can't make comments*

In most cases your SATA HDD only needs to be checked using "chkdsk".
To do so:

Click on Start button

type in: cmd
right click on it (in the results) and click on "Run as an administrator"

let's say your your SATA HDD partition letter is D:
So in the command prompt type: chkdsk d: /f /r

This may take several minutes to complete.

If you had errors in your HDD then you would say in the details screen out of chkdsk statements of corrections to multiple errors.

I hope I've helped.

Comment: Simply running chkdsk will not solve the author's problem.  Only complete and full detailed answers are accepted here at Superuser.  Please be more cautious when providing an answer in the future.  If you want to post comments you will have to provide excellent full detailed on topic answers in the future.